# Comment comprendre «imminent» ici ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Bonjour,

Dans *Voyage au bout de la nuit* :

> Et plus je fuyais l’esclandre et plus on devenait agressif, imminent
> à mon égard.

Comment comprendre *imminent* ici ? Peut-on devenir *imminent* à l'égard de quelqu'un ou s'agit-il d'un jeu de syntaxe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le premier sens de l'adjectif *imminent* est « un emprunt au latin *imminens* (participe présent adjectivé de *immire* « s'élever au-dessus », « être très proche » et « menacer » [...]. Ce verbe se rattache au latin *minae* « saillie, surplomb », à *minax* (→ menace menacer), à *eminere* (→ éminent). [...]

Ce n'est que plus tard (fin XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle) que le mot apparaît avec le sens étymologique de « qui va se produire dans un avenir très proche », en parlant de ce qui menace.

Donc dans ta phrase ça veut dire menaçant.

Source : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey)

Comment: Merci. J'avais pensé qu'il pourrait s'agir aussi d'une ellipse du mot esclandre : "[l'esclandre] imminent à mon égard."

Answer (score 1):

C'est tout simplement le sens « A » de « imminent » dans le TLFi.

> [**imminent**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/imminent) **A.**  − Qui menace.
> ♦ Danger, péril imminent.
> ♦... À mort! Mettons le feu! Tout à coup, l'imminent orage éclata. Des cris de rage et de mort pleuvaient; la tourbe se ruait dans le porche, un moine brandissait une torche sur sa tête (Borel, Champavert,1833, p. 65).